# Color issue in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, colors

I'm writing a function file which is used to draw a line in an image. Now I'm facing the color issue. If I set `color=[255 255 255]` or `color=[128 128 128]` in the command window, the lines that appears in the image are both white.

For `[128 128 128]`, it should be gray color, right? Which is not corresponding to the color table. I have tested some values for the color, the conclusion is that it takes any number greater than zero as 255. How do I fix this problem?

The following is my code.

```
function [ret]=drawline(p1,p2,color,img);
    xmax=size(img,1);
    ymax=size(img,2);
    if (p1(1)>xmax) || (p2(1)>xmax) || (p1(2)>ymax) || (p2(2)>ymax)
        error('value of point is ouside the image.');
    elseif (p1(1)==xmax) || (p2(1)==xmax) || (p1(2)==ymax) || (p2(2)==ymax)
        error('warning: value of point reach the max.');
    elseif (color(1)>256) ||(color(2)>256)||(color(3)>256)
        error('color value is out of range.');
    else
        m=(p2(2)-p1(2))/(p2(1)-p1(1));
        m=round(m);
        c=p1(2)-m*p1(1);
        for  x=linspace(p1(1),p2(1),1000)
            y=m*x+c;
            if p1(1)==p2(1)
               x=p1(1);
               y=p1(1):p2(2);
            end
            img(round(y),round(x),1)=color(1);
            img(round(y),round(x),2)=color(2);
            img(round(y),round(x),3)=color(3);
        end
    end
    ret=img
```

Comment: Please post the code that you have done so far.

Comment: I have post the codes...thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be using floating point images, where the color range is [0, 1] instead of [0, 255].  Perhaps the system is truncating all values over 1 instead of raising an error. I'm not matlab-savvy enough to correct your code, unfortunately.

Comment: You're right. I just need to correct the color range. Once i change the three value between [0 1], desired color come out. Thank you for directing the way out.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you then do `image(img)` in order to display the image. In that case, `[255 255 255]` will correspond to white as a true color value, regardless of the color map. You need to create a monochrome image, which will then be treated as indexed data and displayed using the color map.

See the Tips section of the [image help](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/image.html).

Comment: Yes, after that i need to 'imshow(img)'.Now i left the color problem(as i mentioned above). But i was asked to do the color checking to solve it, which i don't know how to start. And honestly, i have no idea about creating the monochrome image.

Comment: Monochrome means one channel of data. Read the MATLAB help. It's very useful. Mathworks put a lot of effort into it.

Comment: OK. Thanks. By the way, what do you think about the color checking? or you have any suggestions?

Comment: You already have `if (color(1)>256) ||(color(2)>256)||(color(3)>256)`, which should be `if (color(1)>255) ||(color(2)>255)||(color(3)>255)` or `if any(color > 255)`, or possibly `if any(color > 255) || any(color < 0)`. What more do you want?

Comment: I'm struggling on : why i set color=[255 255 255], it gives me a white line, but i set [220 220 220], it still give me a white line. as long as the value is greater than zero, it will take it as 255. how can i make color setting connect to the colormap? so i can get the color corresponding to the colormap.

Comment: What datatype is `img`? i.e. what's the output of `class(img)`?