# How can I return an image in an M-file? (MATLAB)

Tags: image, function, matlab

My function file starts with `function drawline(point1,point2,color,img)`. At the end, I'm supposed to return an image. How do I code the return line?

I posted codes in another Stack Overflow question, *[Color issue in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632068/matlab-color-issue)*.

Comment: since you removed the linked question that contained the code, this question is now meaningless and useless to future visitors.

Comment: Sorry about that. I added the link just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you should be returning the `img` variable, since that's the one you're modifying, not the `image` one, which doesn't exist.

Also, since all the basic types in MATLAB is (effectively) passed by value rather than reference, you need to assign the output argument in order to get anything back. Use the following function call:

```
[img] = drawline(p1,p2,color,img);
```

**EDIT**: Your function should look like this:

```
function img = drawline(p1,p2,color,img)
...
% code that updates IMG.
...
```

Then in the command window you must write

```
[img] = drawline(p1,p2,color,img);
```

An introduction to MATLAB functions can be found here: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/learn_matlab/f4-2525.html.

Comment: So actually i can just take away the output argument [image]? My question is that i don't know how to return. Like, i declare two points in the command window, the color and the img size.But when i type in the 'drawline(a,b,color,img)', i can't see the figure come out. I doubt whether i didn't return the image in the function file that make the problem occur.

Comment: I think i get it. Thank you so much!! sincerely.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to code the return line, just define the function so that it returns an image:

```
function [ Image ] = drawline( point1,point2,color,img )
    ...
    function_instructions
    ...
end
```

the important thing is that you store an image in the Image variable.

In the script that calls the function drawline you should use this kind of statement:

```
 [ Image ] = drawline( point1,point2,color,img );
```

If you need some help on matlab image processing check these out:

- http://amath.colorado.edu/courses/5720/2000Spr/Labs/Worksheets/Matlab_tutorial/matlabimpr.html
- http://www.mathworks.it/help/techdoc/ref/image.html

Comment: Matlab doesn't use curly braces for begin/ end

Comment: its pseudo_code, not exact code. what does it change if I put curly braces instead of the end command. It seems much clear to me with curly braces. and especially your statement has nothing to do with the answer

Comment: Do i need to add 'return' something at the end of the function instruction? I tested in the command window, but after i enter the 'drawline(a,b,color,img)', nothing came out.Did i type the wrong command?

Comment: @Ivy: You should not use a return command. Just store in the variable Image the image you create or process in your function.

Comment: I executed and got an error'??? Output argument "image" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to
"C:\Documents and Settings\student\xdd\drawline.m (drawline)".
', what does it mean?

Comment: I don't know, it's quite difficult to guess without having the code, probably you did some mistake in processing the image, and did not assign a correct value to the variable image the function is returning. Actually this is a different issue from that of the question.

Comment: Anyway, thanks a lot for your help! Actually i'm a new user of Matlab.